# Django, send dictionary to template

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to send a dictionary to a template. And use the django/python magic to work on it client side?

The view function

```
def index(request):

    context = {
               'users' : users,
               'investments' : { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2 },
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And the html

```
{% if investments %}
    <h1>{{ investments['one'] }}</h1> #<---- something like that.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Do you mean {% block name %}?

Answer (score 10):

The code below works in Flask-Jinja, and I believe should work in Django:

```
{% if investments %}
    <h1>{{ investments.one }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Do you happen to know how to retrieve the value if I iterate over the keys like: {% for key in investments %}
   <h1>{{key.items}}</h1>
  {% endfor %}

Comment: @vandelay `{% for key, value in investments.items %} ... {% endfor %}`

Comment: Thanks once again!

Comment: @vandelay if this answer satisfied your question, please accept it